# Dual HDD, Win7 & Ubuntu

Tags: boot, hard-drive, bootloader

I have a pc that has Windows 7 on it, and a hard drive that I recently installed and put Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on.

The problem I encounter is that grub does not load Windows 7, and gives me an error when I try to load from grub. Instead I have to go to the bios and select the other HDD in order to get to Windows 7.

Ideally I would like to be able to use grub to decide which HDD to boot. However, even another boot-loader that allows me to select which HDD to boot would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

Download [this program](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

Install the program if you set it to Grub2Auto it will work.

Comment: If you add a linux entry to the BCD and let EasyBCD auto-locate grub2 it should just find it there for you.

Comment: I've never really had to worry about GRUB before, any tutorials?

Comment: This is what happens when I try to load Windows: 

I select: Windows 7 (loader) (on dev/sda1)

The output: Error: No such device; b040f06540f03426
            Error: Invalid EFI file path